# Types of Joins between 2 tables example - Natural Join

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, natural-join

I have attached the question I am struggling with. So far for the question, I have worked out number of tuples for each type of join

I got : R4 = 15(full join, so 10 in first table & 5 in the second)
R3=?, R2 = 5, and R1 = 10.

The correct answer is the fourth bullet point but I am unsure how to obtain this. Any help would be appreciated!
[image]

Comment: Out of interest, where does the question come from?

Comment: Saw this one earlier this week: 'tuple' from the relational model suggests no nulls and no duplicates but `outer join` implies nulls and SQL implies duplicate rows (not tuples).

Comment: The part you attached is unreadable.  If you want help, do something about that.

Comment: I mean, is this SQL or relational algebra? Are duplicate rows allowed?

Comment: @onedaywhen It states in the question that the common attribute between the tables is the primary key in both, so I would assume no duplicates, and no nulls

Comment: @GarethD: yes but is the result of `TBL1 NATURAL JOIN TBL2` allowed to contain duplicates and/or nulls? What attributes are being projected from each table e.g. if just one non-key attribute was projected and duplicate rows removed then the number of rows could be 1! There seems to be many assumptions to make! Do **you** know where this question comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just consider each join separately, and you can obtain a minumum and maximum row count returned by each.

**R1. TBL1 LEFT NATURAL OUTER JOIN TBL2**

So TBL1 has 10 rows, therefore 10 rows will be returned, there are no other possibilities regardless of what is in TBL2

**R2. TBL1 RIGHT NATURAL OUTER JOIN TBL2**

Similar to above, TBL2 has 5 rows, therefore 5 rows are returned. No other possibilities.

**R3. TBL1 NATURAL JOIN TBL2**

In the absence of a join type ('INNER', `LEFT`, 'RIGHT`or`FULL`) on the JOIn MySQL (and all other DBMS as far as I know) will interpret an`INNER JOIN`, therefore the highest possible number of rows returned is 5, since there are only 5 rows in TBL2, it is possible to return 0 rows though, if there are no matches.

**R4. TBL1 NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN TBL2**

If there are no common values between the two this will return 15 rows, or if all the values in TBL2 are in TBL1, only 10 rows will be returned.

So you have

```
R1. 10
R2. 5
R3. 0-5
R4 10-15
```

So rearanging in terms of order of descending number of rows you get:

```
R4 10-15
R1. 10
R2. 5
R3. 0-5
```

Which is your answer

> R4 >= R1 > R2 >= R3

Comment: Thanks, get it now! Just didn't realise that the R3(natural join) was an inner join, as it didn't actually say inner in the question, but I was obviously supposed to assume it was an inner, which returns only the common attributes (this case - max = 5)

Comment: @GarethD: I would question your last comment: in Standard SQL, `FULL` is an "outer join type" and the `OUTER` keyword is optional, therefore `FULL JOIN` would be `FULL OUTER JOIN`; also `FULL INNER JOIN` is not valid syntax. I tested this on SQL Server (the only thing I have to hand) and the behaviour is per the Standard.

Comment: You are correct, I should have said in the absence of left right or full. On all of these outer is the only possible type. I will edit the answer when I get to a laptop